# What is the general way to determine the type of an OCaml expression?

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml

I am a beginner in OCaml and functional programming in general. If I have an expression, how do I determine its type, other than by just entering it into the top level and compiling it?

For example, if I have

```
fun x -> fun (y, z) -> (x y) (z () )
```

How do I even go about determining the type of this expression? Does it involve any cleverness, or is there a simple algorithm I can follow that will help me think about how to determine the type of any expression?

Comment: It was already done by computers in the 1980s, so it does not involve any cleverness or resource-intensive algorithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No cleverness needed. There is, indeed, an algorithm to determine the types. Ocaml is based on [Hindley-Milner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner)  type system. There are few type inference algorithms, you can find the details in the article. As for your example, let's try figuring it out piece by piece:

```
fun x -> fun (y, z) -> (x y) (z () )
```

- whole expression is a function, from some type `A = typeof(x)` to type of `B = typeof(fun(y, z) -> (x y) (z ()))`.
- `z` is of type `() -> D`, since it is called with `()` and passed to `x`
- so, the type of `z ()` is `D`
- hence the type of `(x y)` is `(D -> E)`
- let `C` be the type of `y`
- type of `x` is therefore `C -> (D -> E)`
- and the type of `(x y) (z ())` is just `E`
- knowing types of `x`, `y` and the last expression, we conclude that the whole expression has the type `(C -> D -> E) -> C * (() -> D) -> E`

Comment: You lost me at `D = typeof(x) = C -> typeof(z ()) -> E`. Would you mind breaking that down a bit? Also, shouldn't that `D` be `A`?

I'm also confused when you say `z` is of type `() -> D` since it is called with `()` and passed to `x`. Isn't it technically passed to `x y`, which will not have the same type as `x`?

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer. Hopefully it is also more clear now, I tried to emphasize bottom-up nature of the calculation more.

Comment: Thank you! This is a wonderful explanation that I am sure I can extrapolate to more complex problems of this nature.

Answer (score 3):

The words to search for are “[Hindley-Milner type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner)”. You should find plenty of resources on the web, just steer clear of research articles which may be arbitrarily complex extensions of the basic system.

There is an algorithm and a type system. The type system is not syntax-directed: at any step a choice must be made to either follow the syntax or instanciate/generalize.

The “algorithm” is syntax-directed (only one rule applies at any step), which is why it is called “algorithm”. That makes it very efficient although it is still presented as a set of inference rules. It can be made more efficient yet by using mutable references for unification.